# Changing the condition of relations in Yii

Tags: join, yii, conditional-statements, has-many, yii-relations

I'm facing a little problem and I need your help. I would like to join two tables, but there would be other conditions for the join not just the foreign key. I have tried setting condition parameter but it creates a WHERE in my query and this will cause that my primary table will be filtered and not the joined one.

```
'dokumentumok' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Fileuploader', 'foreign_id', 'joinType' => 'LEFT JOIN', 'condition' => "(dokumentumok.fileuploader_type='nyomtatvany') AND dokumentumok.fileuploader_deleted = 0"),
```

This would be the condition ->

```
'condition' => "(dokumentumok.fileuploader_type='nyomtatvany') AND dokumentumok.fileuploader_deleted = 0
```

Comment: Also, if you do it a lot, try using scopes. They make life much nicer in the long run

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace `condition` with `on`:

```
'dokumentumok' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Fileuploader', 'foreign_id', 
  'joinType' => 'LEFT JOIN', 
  'on' => "(dokumentumok.fileuploader_type='nyomtatvany') 
  AND dokumentumok.fileuploader_deleted = 0"
)
```

See also: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/10185-using-relations-and-conditions/

Comment: Oh I didn't know there was a option 'on' for relations. I'll try it! Thanks for your help! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Or for example.

**In relation**

> 'dokumentumok' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Fileuploader', 'foreign_id');

**And get model**

> YouModelName::model()->with(array('dokumentumok' => array('on' =>
>   "(dokumentumok.fileuploader_type='nyomtatvany')    AND
>   dokumentumok.fileuploader_deleted = 0")))->findAll();